# i made a function but got a 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python

this is my code when i try to run it it says  'NoneType' object is not callable
what is wrong?   im a begginer so dont be rude :D
the output should be:
Subtraction result is 24
Subtraction result is -6
passed numbers are: 9 i 15

```
def addition(func):
    def wrapper_function(a,b):
        print("Subtraction result is {}".format(a+b))
        return func(a,b)
        return wrapper_function


def subtraction(func):
    def wrapper_function(a,b):
        print("Subtraction result is {}".format(a-b))
        return func(a,b)
        return wrapper_function

@addition
@subtraction
def operations(a,b):
    print("passed numbers are: {} i {}".format(a,b))

operations(9, 15)
```

Comment: `return wrapper_function` is indented wrong in both places. It should be un-indented one level. Voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you try to achieve here? What's the input and output? To help people understand it better. `Learn how to ask` is very helpful...and important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the two `return wrapper_function` are wrongly intended, they're associated to the `wrapper_function()` (and never execute because another `return` precedes them):

```py
def addition(func):
    def wrapper_function(a,b):
        print("Subtraction result is {}".format(a+b))
        return func(a,b)
    return wrapper_function


def subtraction(func):
    def wrapper_function(a,b):
        print("Subtraction result is {}".format(a-b))
        return func(a,b)
    return wrapper_function

@addition
@subtraction
def operations(a,b):
    print("passed numbers are: {} i {}".format(a,b))

operations(9, 15)
```

Comment: oh wow thx ... i feel stupid    im a beginer tho thx so much for helping me figure it out